# Finding the companies when removing NAs in R

Tags: r, dplyr, na

I am working with a panel data, which I am filtering by removing NAs for different variables step by step and creating new data-frames.

For example passing from a panel_data1 to panel_data2 while removing NAs for additional variables, 399 companies are removed. Is there a way I can retrieve these companies in a new dataset, as I want to have the companies (amlong with their respective data) that I am losing.

**Panel_data**

```
structure(list(ISIN = c("AEA000201011", "AEA000201011", "AEA000201011", 
"AEA000201011", "AEA000201011", "AEA000201011", "AEA000201011", 
"AEA000201011", "AEA000201011", "AEA000201011", "AEA000201011", 
"AEA000801018", "AEA000801018", "AEA000801018", "AEA000801018", 
"AEA000801018", "AEA000801018", "AEA000801018", "AEA000801018", 
"AEA000801018", "AEA000801018", "AEA000801018", "AEA001501013", 
"AEA001501013", "AEA001501013"), year = c(2010L, 2011L, 2012L, 
2013L, 2014L, 2015L, 2016L, 2017L, 2018L, 2019L, 2020L, 2010L, 
2011L, 2012L, 2013L, 2014L, 2015L, 2016L, 2017L, 2018L, 2019L, 
2020L, 2010L, 2011L, 2012L), full_company_name = c("Abu Dhabi Commercial Bank PJSC", 
"Abu Dhabi Commercial Bank PJSC", "Abu Dhabi Commercial Bank PJSC", 
"Abu Dhabi Commercial Bank PJSC", "Abu Dhabi Commercial Bank PJSC", 
"Abu Dhabi Commercial Bank PJSC", "Abu Dhabi Commercial Bank PJSC", 
"Abu Dhabi Commercial Bank PJSC", "Abu Dhabi Commercial Bank PJSC", 
"Abu Dhabi Commercial Bank PJSC", "Abu Dhabi Commercial Bank PJSC", 
"Abu Dhabi Islamic Bank PJSC", "Abu Dhabi Islamic Bank PJSC", 
"Abu Dhabi Islamic Bank PJSC", "Abu Dhabi Islamic Bank PJSC", 
"Abu Dhabi Islamic Bank PJSC", "Abu Dhabi Islamic Bank PJSC", 
"Abu Dhabi Islamic Bank PJSC", "Abu Dhabi Islamic Bank PJSC", 
"Abu Dhabi Islamic Bank PJSC", "Abu Dhabi Islamic Bank PJSC", 
"Abu Dhabi Islamic Bank PJSC", "Arabtec Holding PJSC", "Arabtec Holding PJSC", 
"Arabtec Holding PJSC"), refin_esg = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, 48.74, 
54.32, 63.81, 67.64, 71.74, 68.17, 63.8, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, 30.89, NA, NA, NA, NA), refin_e = c(NA, NA, NA, 
NA, 23.21, 53.02, 60.18, 18.64, 50.25, 52.21, 46.69, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 20.52, NA, NA, NA, NA), esg_msci_hist = c(NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, 70, 84, 73, 74, 63, 71, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), env_msci_hist = c(NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, 29, 17, 20, 19, 14, 26, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), ESG_spg = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 35, 
36, 37, 26, 20, 15, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 8, 6, 
NA, NA, NA), E_spg = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 18, 26, 26, 15, 12, 
2, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 6, 0, NA, NA, NA)), row.names = c(NA, 
25L), class = "data.frame")
```

**panel_data1**

```
panel_data1 <- panel_data %>% filter(!is.na(refin_e) & !is.na(refin_esg) &
                                        !is.na(sc1_refin) & !is.na(sc2_refin) &
                                        !is.na(sct_refin) & !is.na(sc12inten_refin) &
                                        !is.na(E_spg) & !is.na(ESG_spg) & !is.na(mktcap) &
                                        !is.na(carbonscope1_trucost) &
                                        !is.na(carbonscope2_trucost) & !is.na(carbon_inten_scope1_trucost) &
                                        !is.na(carbon_inten_scope2_trucost) &
                                        !is.na(env_msci_hist) & !is.na(esg_msci_hist) &
                                        !is.na(scope1_msci_carb) & !is.na(scope2_msci_carb) &
                                        !is.na(scope12_msci_carb) & !is.na(scope12inten_msci_carb))
```

The output of this data is 2103 companies.

**panel_data2**

```
panel_data2 <- panel_data %>%
  filter(!is.na(refin_e) & !is.na(refin_esg) &
           !is.na(sc1_refin) & !is.na(sc2_refin) &
           !is.na(sct_refin) & !is.na(sc12inten_refin) &
           !is.na(E_spg) & !is.na(ESG_spg) & !is.na(mktcap) &
           !is.na(carbonscope1_trucost) &
           !is.na(carbonscope2_trucost) &
           !is.na(carbon_inten_scope1_trucost) &
           !is.na(carbon_inten_scope2_trucost) &
           !is.na(env_msci_hist) & !is.na(esg_msci_hist) &
           !is.na(scope1_msci_carb) & !is.na(scope2_msci_carb) &
           !is.na(scope12_msci_carb) &
           !is.na(scope12inten_msci_carb) &
           !is.na(carbonscope3_trucost) &
           !is.na(sc3_refin) & !is.na(scope3_msci_carb) &
           !is.na(carbon_inten_scope3_trucost))
```

The output of this data is 1704.

I want to be able to have a new data frame with the 399 that were dropped, if possible

Comment: Yes, sorry that was just an error, I modified it

Comment: Hi Darren. Sorry if it is anoying, it is my first time asking a question in stackoverflow, I am trying to learn how to do it the right way. I am trying to find a solution so making it harder for your to understand is not the goal. I will try to simplify it

Comment: Have you tried `dplyr::setdiff(panel_data1, panel_data2)`? (The leading `dplyr::` is necessary)

Comment: I did, and it is not giving me the 399 companies that is the difference between the panel_datas, but instead 1953..

Comment: Alright, with limited clues, I can just "guess" how to help you. Maybe you can edit the post to clarify more and provide a simplified example and the expected output. Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

It's unclear from your code whether you are testing all columns or just a subset. Either way, though, it is *far* more efficient to use `complete.cases(.)` somehow.

```r
dat1 <- dat %>%
  filter(complete.cases(cur_data()))
dat2 <- dat %>%
  filter(!complete.cases(cur_data()))
dat1
#           ISIN year              full_company_name refin_esg refin_e esg_msci_hist env_msci_hist ESG_spg E_spg
# 1 AEA000201011 2015 Abu Dhabi Commercial Bank PJSC     54.32   53.02            70            29      35    18
# 2 AEA000201011 2016 Abu Dhabi Commercial Bank PJSC     63.81   60.18            84            17      36    26
# 3 AEA000201011 2017 Abu Dhabi Commercial Bank PJSC     67.64   18.64            73            20      37    26
# 4 AEA000201011 2018 Abu Dhabi Commercial Bank PJSC     71.74   50.25            74            19      26    15
# 5 AEA000201011 2019 Abu Dhabi Commercial Bank PJSC     68.17   52.21            63            14      20    12
# 6 AEA000201011 2020 Abu Dhabi Commercial Bank PJSC     63.80   46.69            71            26      15     2
dat2
#            ISIN year              full_company_name refin_esg refin_e esg_msci_hist env_msci_hist ESG_spg E_spg
# 1  AEA000201011 2010 Abu Dhabi Commercial Bank PJSC        NA      NA            NA            NA      NA    NA
# 2  AEA000201011 2011 Abu Dhabi Commercial Bank PJSC        NA      NA            NA            NA      NA    NA
# 3  AEA000201011 2012 Abu Dhabi Commercial Bank PJSC        NA      NA            NA            NA      NA    NA
# 4  AEA000201011 2013 Abu Dhabi Commercial Bank PJSC        NA      NA            NA            NA      NA    NA
# 5  AEA000201011 2014 Abu Dhabi Commercial Bank PJSC     48.74   23.21            NA            NA      NA    NA
# 6  AEA000801018 2010    Abu Dhabi Islamic Bank PJSC        NA      NA            NA            NA      NA    NA
# 7  AEA000801018 2011    Abu Dhabi Islamic Bank PJSC        NA      NA            NA            NA      NA    NA
# 8  AEA000801018 2012    Abu Dhabi Islamic Bank PJSC        NA      NA            NA            NA      NA    NA
# 9  AEA000801018 2013    Abu Dhabi Islamic Bank PJSC        NA      NA            NA            NA      NA    NA
# 10 AEA000801018 2014    Abu Dhabi Islamic Bank PJSC        NA      NA            NA            NA      NA    NA
# 11 AEA000801018 2015    Abu Dhabi Islamic Bank PJSC        NA      NA            NA            NA      NA    NA
# 12 AEA000801018 2016    Abu Dhabi Islamic Bank PJSC        NA      NA            NA            NA      NA    NA
# 13 AEA000801018 2017    Abu Dhabi Islamic Bank PJSC        NA      NA            NA            NA      NA    NA
# 14 AEA000801018 2018    Abu Dhabi Islamic Bank PJSC        NA      NA            NA            NA      NA    NA
# 15 AEA000801018 2019    Abu Dhabi Islamic Bank PJSC     30.89   20.52            NA            NA       8     6
# 16 AEA000801018 2020    Abu Dhabi Islamic Bank PJSC        NA      NA            NA            NA       6     0
# 17 AEA001501013 2010           Arabtec Holding PJSC        NA      NA            NA            NA      NA    NA
# 18 AEA001501013 2011           Arabtec Holding PJSC        NA      NA            NA            NA      NA    NA
# 19 AEA001501013 2012           Arabtec Holding PJSC        NA      NA            NA            NA      NA    NA
```

It would actually be a bit shorter code to use base R, as in

```r
dat1 <- dat[complete.cases(date),]
dat2 <- dat[!complete.cases(date),]
```

but I was continuing with the apparent preference for `dplyr`. They both produce the same results.

If you're using a subset, you can use them specifically instead of the full frame. For example, if I only care about the last two columns of your sample data, then

```r
dat %>%
  filter(complete.cases(ESG_spg, E_spg))
#           ISIN year              full_company_name refin_esg refin_e esg_msci_hist env_msci_hist ESG_spg E_spg
# 1 AEA000201011 2015 Abu Dhabi Commercial Bank PJSC     54.32   53.02            70            29      35    18
# 2 AEA000201011 2016 Abu Dhabi Commercial Bank PJSC     63.81   60.18            84            17      36    26
# 3 AEA000201011 2017 Abu Dhabi Commercial Bank PJSC     67.64   18.64            73            20      37    26
# 4 AEA000201011 2018 Abu Dhabi Commercial Bank PJSC     71.74   50.25            74            19      26    15
# 5 AEA000201011 2019 Abu Dhabi Commercial Bank PJSC     68.17   52.21            63            14      20    12
# 6 AEA000201011 2020 Abu Dhabi Commercial Bank PJSC     63.80   46.69            71            26      15     2
# 7 AEA000801018 2019    Abu Dhabi Islamic Bank PJSC     30.89   20.52            NA            NA       8     6
# 8 AEA000801018 2020    Abu Dhabi Islamic Bank PJSC        NA      NA            NA            NA       6     0
```

Comment: The panel_data `dput()` was just a smaller subset of my main dataset but I have over 9K companies and over 36 columns so impossible to put the entire output here. In panel_data1 I have removed NAs for only a few variables that interest me as I wanted to see how many compaies that would removed. In panel_data2 I removed NAs for a few more variables in the dataset. I want to retrieve the companies that were removed between panel_data1 and panel_data2

Comment: That's my `dat2`. If you want to filter ALL columns, then the first example works, otherwise `complete.cases(refin_e, refin_esg, ...)` produces the same results as `!is.na(refin_e) & !is.na(refin_esg) & ...` and for more readable and maintainable (in my opinion). If this produces the intended results, then you may consider accepting but I think we're "done" here; otherwise (and more importantly), if it does not, please be clear on your expected output. Thanks!